# Multiple inheritance pointer comparison

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, multiple-inheritance

I have a class `Derived` that inherits directly from two base classes, `Base1` and `Base2`. I'd like to know if it's safe, in general, to compare pointers to the base classes to determine if they are the same `Derived` object:

```
Base1* p1;
Base2* p2;

/*
 * Stuff happens here. p1 and p2 now point to valid objects of either their
 * base type or Derived
 */

//assert(p1 == p2); //This is illegal
assert(p1 == static_cast<Base1*>(p2)); //Is this ok?
assert(static_cast<Derived*>(p1) == static_cast<Derived*>(p2)); //How about this?
```

The pointers are guaranteed to be valid, but not necessarily to point to a `Derived` object. My guess is that this is probably fine, but I wanted to know if it was ok from a technical C++ perspective. I actually never do any operations on the pointers, I just want to know if they point to the same object.

EDIT: It seems to be safe if I can guarantee that `p1` and `p2` point to `Derrived` objects. I basically want to know if it is safe if they don't- if one or both point to a base object, will the comparison necessarily fail? Again, I can guarantee the pointers are valid (i.e., `p1` would never point at a `Base2` object or vice versa)

Comment: I was under the impression that c++ did not support multiple inheritance.  do you mean "Base1->Base2->Derived"

Comment: C++ does indeed support multiple inheritance :)

Comment: It's one of the easiest ways to shoot yourself in the foot, but yes, C++ supports MI

Comment: "_It's one of the easiest ways to shoot yourself in the foot_" No.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, no, it won't work.

I'm personally a big fan of learning-by-example, so here's one:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base1
{
public:
    Base1()
    {
        numberBase1 = 1;
    }

    int numberBase1;
};

class Base2
{
public:
    Base2()
    {
        numberBase2 = 2;
    }

    int numberBase2;
};

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        numberDerived = 3;
    }

    int numberDerived;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base1 *b1 = &d;
    Base2 *b2 = &d;

    std::cout << "d: " << &d << ", b1: " << b1 << ", b2: " << b2 << ", d.numberDerived: " << &(d.numberDerived) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

One run-through on my computer outputted this:

```
d: 0035F9FC, b1: 0035F9FC, b2: 0035FA00, d.numberDerived: 0035FA04
```

Soo.. If we define the address of d as 0, then b1 is 0, b2 is +4 and the number of d is +8. This is because an int on my machine is 4 byte long.

Basically, you have to look at the layout of how C++ internally represents a class:

```
Address:    Class:
0           Base1
4           Base2
8           Derived
```

.. So in total, instantiating a Derived class will allocate space for the base classes of the derived class, and finally make room for the derived object itself. Since we have 3 integers here, that'll be 12 bytes.

Now, what you're asking (unless I misunderstood something) is if you can compare the address of the different base class pointers to each other to see if they point to the same object, and the answer is no - Not directly at least, as in my example, b1 would point to 0035F9FC, while b2 would point to 0035FA00. In C++, this offsetting is all done at compile time.

You could probably do some magic with RIIA and sizeof() and determine how much of an offset b2 should have to be comparable to b1, but then you run into all kinds of other trouble like virtuals. In short, I would not recommend this approach.

A much better way would be to cast to Derived* like ialiashkevich said, however, that would impose a problem if your object was not an instance of Derived*.

(Disclaimer; I haven't used C++ in 3-4 years, so I might be a bit off my game. Be gentle :) )

Answer (score 6):

Casting to `Derived*` before comparison is the right way to go.

There is a similar topic: [C++ pointer multi-inheritance fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157104/c-pointer-multi-inheritance-fun)

Comment: "pointers are guaranteed to be valid, but not necessarily to point to a Derived object". This is not to say your suggestion won't work, but you must use `dynamic_cast`, and you must handle the case they both return NULL (which might or might not mean they point on the same object).

Comment: Oh they'll never be null- I thought I mentioned that. They're guaranteed to point at a valid object of their type.

Comment: @Lucretiel, if you call `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p)` and `p` points to a valid object of type `Base1`, the call will return `NULL`. Directly comparing such a cast to two `Base1`s will always return true, since `NULL == NULL`. Those two `Base1`s might not be the same object, though.

Comment: @ialiash -- If you allow me, I'll add my example (see my answer) to your answer and delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, turns out the shortest way to achieve what you're looking for is:

```
assert(dynamic_cast<void*>(p1) == dynamic_cast<void*>(p2));
```

Dynamically casting to `void*` effectively down-casts the given pointer to its most derived class, so you're guaranteed if both point on the same object, the assert won't fail.

Indeed, [there are practical uses for dynamic-casting to void pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123776/are-there-practical-uses-for-dynamic-casting-to-void-pointer)...

Edit: to answer the question's edit, the comparison **is not** safe. Consider the following code:

```
Base2 b2;
Base1 b1;
assert(static_cast<Derived*>(&b1) == static_cast<Derived*>(&b2));  // succeeds!
```

The memory layout of the two different bases is similar to that of a `Derived` (on a common implementation - the stack grows opposite of the heap). The first `static_cast` leaves the pointer as is, but the second one moves the pointer `sizeof(Base1)` back, so now they both point on `&b1`, and the assert succeeds - even though the objects are different.

You should use `static_cast` only if you know for sure the cast is correct. This is not your case, so you must use `dynamic_cast`, possibly as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, this is generally not a good idea.

**NOTE**: This is assuming you want custom equivalence for all of your classes, if you want to check if they are the same object, it is better to do `(Derived *)`.

A much better solution would be to overload the `==` operator for `Base1`, `Base2`, and `Derived`.

Assuming `Base1` has 1 parameter `param1` for equality and `Base2` has another parameter `param2` for equality:

```
virtual bool Base1::operator==(object& other){
    return false;
}

virtual bool Base1::operator==(Base1& other)
{
    return this.param1 == other.param1;
}

virtual bool Base2::operator==(object& other){
    return false;
}

virtual bool Base2::operator==(Base2& other)
{
    return this.param2 == other.param2;
}

virtual bool Derived::operator==(object& other){
    return false;
}

virtual bool Derived::operator==(Derived& other){
    return this.param1 == other.param1 && this.param2 == other.param2;
}

virtual bool Derived::operator==(Base1& other){
    return this.param1 == other.param1;
}

virtual bool Derived::operator==(Base2& other){
    return this.param2 == other.param2;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Lucretiel, I thought you were checking for object equality, not object identity. I'm leaving my answer up as a reference to future visitors, but you should accept ialiashkevich's answer

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be invalid, based on this SO question:
[How is C++'s multiple inheritance implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002503/how-is-cs-multiple-inheritance-implemented)

Basically, because of the way the objects are laid out in memory, a cast to either `Base1*` or `Base2*` results in a mutation of the pointer that I can't arbitrarily reverse at runtime without a `dynamic_cast`, which I'd like to avoid. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can avoid `dynamic_cast` only if you know the type of the pointed object for sure. Please see my answer for more.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dynamic_cast`, and watch out for NULL.

```
#include <cassert>

struct Base1 { virtual ~Base1() {} };
struct Base2 { virtual ~Base2() {} };
struct Derived : Base1, Base2 {};

bool IsEqual(Base1 *p1, Base2 *p2) {
  Derived *d1 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p1);
  Derived *d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p2);

  if( !d1 || !d2 ) return false;
  return d1 == d2;
}

int main () {
  Derived d;
  Base1 *p1 = &d;
  Base2 *p2 = &d;
  Base1 b1;
  Base2 b2;

  assert(IsEqual(p1, p2));
  assert(!IsEqual(p1, &b2));
  assert(!IsEqual(&b1, p2));
  assert(!IsEqual(&b1, &b2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
assert(p1 == p2);                      //This is illegal
assert(p1 == static_cast<Base1*>(p2)); //Is this ok?
assert(static_cast<Derived*>(p1) 
       == static_cast<Derived*>(p2));  //How about this?
```

None of them is a *good* solution. The first one will not compile, as you cannot compare pointers of unrelated types. The second one will not compile either (unless `Base1` and `Base2` are related through inheritance) for the same reason: you cannot `static_cast` to a pointer of an unrelated type.

The third option is *borderline*. That is, it is not correct, but it will work in many cases (as long as inheritance is not virtual).

The proper way of comparing for identity would be using `dynamic_cast` to the derived type and checking for null:

```
{
  Derived *tmp = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p1);
  assert( tmp && tmp == dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p2) );
{
```